# Adding objects to nsmutablearray swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsmutablearray

I added the string objects inside the mutablearray :

```
let photoArray: NSMutableArray = []
for photo in media {
    photoArray.add("\(photo.fileName ?? "")")
}
```

Then I get an output like:

```
<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x1c02069e0>(
  (
     "Car",
     "Dog",
     "Tree"
  )
)
```

But I want this :

```
(
     "Car",
     "Dog",
     "Tree"
)
```

Is there any way to get the output like that?

Comment: What do you mean by you want an output like this? Do you mean printing in  console? Where is your code to print said array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, it works for me perfectly.

```
var photoArray = [String]()
for photo in media {
    let fileName = photo.fileName ?? ""
    print("fileName - \(fileName)")
    photoArray.append(fileName)
}
print("\n\n** photoArray - \n\(photoArray)")
```

> result = ["Car", "Dog", "Tree"]

Comment: I got an error `Value of type '[String]' has no member 'add'` at `photoArray.add(fileName)`

Comment: @SeizeDuh Updated now. Try again with `append` method.